# sql combine multiple query into one?

Tags: mysql, sql

NOTE: NO `JOIN` please.

Let's say I got a table `user` with a field name `gender`. The `gender` value may be `0`, `1`, `-1`.

I want to know the quantity of those there value respectively.
What I knew is using three sql queries as below.

```
select count(1) from user where gender=0
select count(1) from user where gender=1
select count(1) from user where gender=-1
```

Question: how to combine the above into one query?
btw, I am newbee to SQL.

Comment: were you going to add anything else to your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
select gender, count(*) 
from user 
group by gender
```

Comment: Ninja, I was just about to write to use `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

The `GROUP BY` is most likely to serve you best. However, your only restriction is "NO JOIN". This would allow (in addition to the `GROUP BY`) for either one of

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM User WHERE gender = 0) AS genderNought
  , (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM User WHERE gender = 1) AS genderOne
  , (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM User WHERE gender = -1) AS genderMinusOne;
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS hits, gender, 'genderNought' AS genderInWords FROM User WHERE gender = 0 UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(1), gender, 'genderOne' FROM User WHERE gender = 1 UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(1), gender, 'genderMinusOne' FROM User WHERE gender = -1;
```

as well.

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b306/1).

Comment: "The GROUP BY is most likely to serve you best. However, you asked for "NO JOIN"." - since when was a GROUP BY considered a  join?

Comment: Never over here - but the two options, I offered, are (at least to me) "NO JOIN"s either. Thus, I thought, it to be OK to point them out… Will re-phrase…